# Is displacement related to velocity or mass (in this question)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

> Two blocks of masses $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ are kept on a smooth horizontal surface. A spring of mass $m$ and natural length $L$ connects the two blocks as shown in the figure. At t=0, $m_1$ and $m_{2}$ are given velocities $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$. Just after t=0, what is the value of $x$ so that the point $P$ remains at rest?
> [image: question figure]

This is my solution:
Since $\omega$ is the property of the source, it should remain the same for one spring.

$$\omega=\sqrt{\frac {k_1}{m_1}} ~~\&~~ \omega=\sqrt{\frac {k_2}{m_2}}$$
$$\therefore \frac{k_1}{k_2}=\frac{m_1}{m_2}$$
For point $P$ to be in rest net force on spring should be $0$.
$$\therefore k_1x = k_2(L-x)\Rightarrow\frac{k_1}{k_2}x=L-x\Rightarrow\frac{m_1}{m_2}x=L-x$$
$$\Rightarrow m_1x=m_2L-m_2x\Rightarrow x(m_1+m_2)=m_2L$$
$$\therefore x = \frac{m_2L}{m_1+m_2}$$

This expression is in the options but not the answer.

This is the solution the source states:

> [image: solution as stated by source]

Edit: **Knowing why my approach is wrong is more valuable to me than knowing why is the solution correct.**

Comment: On the sketch, $m_2$ is missing.  Also x and L should be measured from the right side of $m_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The masses of the blocks are irrelevant - this is purely a question about the geometry of the situation.

We can assume the spring stretches uniformly along its length, so the velocity $v(x)$ of a point on the spring at distance $x$ from $m_1$ will vary linearly from $-v_1$ at $x=0$ to $v_2$ at $x=L$. So

$v(x) = \frac {(v_1+v_2)} L x - v_1$

When $v(x) = 0$ we have

$\frac {(v_1+v_2)} L x - v_1 = 0 \\ \Rightarrow x = \frac {v_1 L}{v_1+v_2}$

Comment: I understand that this method (of writing the linear equation of $v-x$ and then solving it) is correct, but where is my approach wrong?

Comment: @mmaismma I think you are implicitly assuming that the centre of mass of the system is at rest. We don't know this, because the system has been given momentum $m_2v_2-m_1v_1$ which need not be zero. Note that *if* $m_2v_2=m_1v_1$ then your solution and the correct solution are the same.

Comment: As much as this comment convinces me theoretically, I still can not understand why my solution is wrong mathematically. I am doing only two things. 1) The $\omega$ part is true as it needs to be constant for one spring. 2) I am assuming that the spring is at rest and thus equating net force on it to 0. Can you point out which part is wrong and how?

Answer (score 0):

If impulses are applied simultaneously at the ends of a massive spring, each will travel at the same speed down the spring, and the center of the spring will be the last part of the spring to move.